# How to remove axis dashes in OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot and trying to show only the plot. I have found a way to make the axis numbers, the axes, and the background transparent. But I can't seem to find a way to make the axes dashes transparent:

[image: Axis dashes.]

Here's the code that I use:

```
<oxy:Plot Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" TextColor="Transparent" PlotAreaBorderColor="Transparent">
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding CoilData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" DataFieldX="Key" DataFieldY="Value"/>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it by using the following:

```
<oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" TickStyle="None"/>
    <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" TickStyle="None"/>
</oxy:Plot.Axes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this properties of Linear Axis :

```
LinearAxis eje_y=new LinearAxis();
eje_y.MinorTickSize = 0;
eje_y.MajorTickSize = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the axes to be visible, set their `IsAxisVisible` property to `false`. You still need to add them so that the default axis/value is overwritten.